# Dias de la semana SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server

como hacer para generar una columna que muestre los siguientes datos 1(0sm+1d)
siendo estos diasacomulado(numero de semana + dia de la semana)

ejemplo:

- 1(0sm+1d)
- 2(0sm+2d)
- 3(0sm+3d)
- 4(0sm+4d)
- 5(0sm+5d)
- 6(0sm+6d)
- 7(0sm+7d)
- 8(1sm+1d)
- 9(1sm+2d)
- 10(1sm+3d)
- 11(1sm+4d)
- 12(1sm+5d)

hasta vengo probando con:

```
cast(convert(varchar,(DATEDIFF(day, @date, IR.[Date])) +1) + '(' + convert(varchar,(DATEDIFF(DAY, @date, IR.[Date]) / 7)) +'sm+' + convert(varchar,(DATEDIFF(WEEKDAY, @date, IR.[Date])) +1) + 'd)' as nvarchar(300)) as 'D'
```

siendo @date una fecha cualquiera.

esto actualmente me duevuelve:
daysAcomulados(semana + )
pero no me devuelve bien los dias de la semana:
alguien sabe como hacer para que devuelva en los dias de la semana un numero del 1 al 7 dependiendo del dia de la semana?

Comment: ¿A que te refieres con los días de la semana? ¿Asignar 1 al lunes, 2 al martes y así, o 1 al primer día que tengas, 2 al siguiente y hasta llegar a 7? ¿Por qué tienes 0 semanas más 7 días? ¿No debería ser una semana y cero días?

Comment: los dias son indiferente porque arranca desde el primer dia (no importa cual) como semana 0 y dia 1, lo que me hace falta terminar que no me sale es hacer que cuando los dias llegue al dia 7 se reinicie

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a [es.so]. Puede serte de interés realizar el [tour] y leer [ask]. Crear un escenario claro servirá para que te apoyen y te den un resultado, correcto. Por otro lado, para al llegar al día 7 se reinicie. Divide tu resultado entre 7 y ya lo tienes. Pero te recomiendo, que prepares un buen escenario, que la respuesta seguro que será la apropiada. Un script de creación de datos, Un script que lo alimente. Y el resultado esperado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que hago, en casos como este, es aislar el problema para poder concentrarme primero en su solución y finalmente integrarlo en donde haga falta.

Para lograr la cadena que quieres, primero hay que figurarse las operaciones aritméticas que hay que hacer sobre el número de día para obtener la *semana* y *día de la semana* que la formarán.

Una vez hecho esto, es trivial concatenar todo en una cadena.

En el ejemplo a continuación, obtengo números consecutivos desde una tabla del sistema, y luego aplico estos pasos para obtener el número de semana y día de la semana, finalmente ensamblo todo en una cadena:

```
with
num(n) as (
select row_number() over (order by (select null)) from sys.all_columns
)
select   n día
       , (n-1)/7 semana
       , iif(n%7<>0, n%7, 7) diasemana
       ,   cast(n as varchar) 
         + '('
         + cast((n-1)/7 as varchar) 
         + 'sm+'
         + cast(iif(n%7<>0, n%7, 7) as varchar) 
         + 'd)' SemanasDias
  from num
```

El resultado que arroja va así:

```
día       semana diasemana SemanasDias
--------- ------ --------- ------------------
1         0      1         1(0sm+1d)
2         0      2         2(0sm+2d)
3         0      3         3(0sm+3d)
4         0      4         4(0sm+4d)
5         0      5         5(0sm+5d)
6         0      6         6(0sm+6d)
7         0      7         7(0sm+7d)
8         1      1         8(1sm+1d)
9         1      2         9(1sm+2d)
10        1      3         10(1sm+3d)
11        1      4         11(1sm+4d)
12        1      5         12(1sm+5d)
13        1      6         13(1sm+6d)
...
...
11181     1597   2         11181(1597sm+2d)
11182     1597   3         11182(1597sm+3d)
11183     1597   4         11183(1597sm+4d)
11184     1597   5         11184(1597sm+5d)

(11184 rows affected)

Completion time: 2021-05-28T09:37:14.9988306-06:00
```

Para evitar escribir tanta fórmula, puedes lograr el mismo resultado valiéndote de una sentencia `cross apply`:

```
select cast(num.n as varchar) 
         + '('
         + cast(x.semana as varchar) 
         + 'sm+'
         + cast(x.diasemana as varchar) 
         + 'd)' SemanasDias
  from num
       cross apply (select (n-1)/7 semana, iif(n%7<>0, n%7, 7) diasemana) x
```

Que tiene la ventaja, además, de ser mucho más legible. Si no lo conoces `apply` hay un excelente artículo sobre [el operador *apply*](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2020/06/27/operador-apply/) de @javifer2, su lectura no tiene desperdicio.